# PostgreSQL integer array value join to integer in other table with desc string

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, select, postgresql-9.1

I have a table `test` column with int arrays and values like `{1000,4000,6000}` or `{1000}` or `{1000,4000}` called `ekw`.
These values match to a description string in another table

```
tab: test
id | name   | ekw
-----------------
 1 |  One   | {1000}
 2 |  Two   | {1000,4000}
 3 |  Three | {1000,4000,6000}

tab: ekwdesc
id | value  | desc
-----------------
 1 |  1000  | Max
 2 |  2000  | Tim
 3 |  3000  | Rita
 5 |  4000  | Sven
 6 |  5000  | Tom
 7 |  6000  | Bob
```

is it possible to select these columns and print the strings?

something like:

```
select name, ekw from test, ekwdesc
```

I would like to see this result:

```
id | name   | ekwdesc
-----------------
 1 |  One   | Max
 2 |  Two   | Max, Sven
 3 |  Three | Max, Sven, Bob
```

I tried with IN and ANY but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 19):

You had the right idea to use the `any` operator for the join. Once the join is complete, all that's left is to use [`string_agg`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-aggregate.html) to transform the result to the format you want:

```
SELECT   name, STRING_AGG(description, ', ')
FROM     test
JOIN     ekwdesc ON ekwdesc.value = ANY(test.ekw)
GROUP BY name
```

See the attached [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/113d1/1) for an executable example.

Comment: Does this assure that the description tags will be returned in the right order -- the order of the values in the ekw array?

Comment: @Sigfried Nope.

Comment: Can this solution be changed to work in case, where main table has json fields? as you know, you can't use group by for json columns.

Comment: @eyeinthebrick Not sure I understand what you're asking. Could you perhaps post a new question with the new problem statement?

Comment: Only similar question and answer found, that too doesn't work. Array should be on right side error. Checked so many things nothing worked for my jsonb[] case.